# Function that returns 1D array and writes the results to a text file

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I've been asked to write a code that takes 2, 1D arrays from a text file, add them and then return the results to another text file. Yet, I still get errors about pointers. I'm a C newbie and I'll be very happy if someone could explain it to me.

```
int result(int a[], int b[])
{
  int *wsk = &c_tab[0];
  char choice;
  printf("0.Add\n1.Substract");
  scanf("%c", &choice);
  for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (choice== '0')
    {
      *wsk = a[i] + b[i];
      wsk++;
    }
    else if (choice== '1')
    {
      *wsk = a[i] - b [i];
      wsk++
    }
  }
  return *wsk;
}
```

Comment: A picture of code cannot be compiled. The code in your picture, even when typed in, cannot be build into a binary. Polish should not be a problem, but surprisingly it is in your interest to translate even code identifiers; if they are any good they help understanding. "get errors about pointers" is a very short, not to say useless summary of your problem. Please consider making a [mcve] and explaining in more detail what happens and what should happen.

Comment: Please consider what kind of help you want. Do you expect an explanation? Then why don't you explain your problem in detail? Do you want code? Then why don't you provide code yourself? A picture of code which does not make a program is not the same thing.

Comment: It's my first time using Stack. I'm sorry for all the errors - I was in a hurry. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error I see is that you need to declare the function type with the type of the returned value, in this case the function has to be:

```
int *dzialanie(int a[], int b[]){
    ...
    return wsk;
}
```

Another error is in the for loop, the operation has to be:

```
...
for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
    *(wsk + i) = a[i] + b[i];
}
...
```

Same for the another (See that you didn't declare the i which is a variable too). Another way, is doing:

```
wsk[i] = a[i] - b[i];
```

Is the same.
If you already know the dimension of the two arrays, maybe is better to take the arguments as pointers, it will look like:

```
int dzialanie(int *a, int *b){
    ...
}
```

And you will have to allocate memory, this coul be done with malloc:

```
wsk = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
```

At the end of your program you will want to free that allocated memory, doing:

```
free(wsk);
```

Hope you understand, my english is poor, I'm from Argentina. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

since you are using a global variable the return type should be void(and or some form of indication that the calculation has been done. which in turn could be a simple return value of -1 or w/e(i'll leave that part up to you).

```
int res[10]; // global variable

void add(int *a, int *b) // no return value, new array will be saved globally(not advisable)
{
    int sign = -1; // your +- check
    printf("0.Suma\n1.Roznica");
    scanf("%c", &sign);
    if (sign == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            res[i] = a[i] + b[i]; 
    }
    else if (sign == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            res[i] = a[i] - b[i]; 
    }
}
```

an alternative way of doing it would be to use either a or b as "return" values with a simple change like `a[i] += b[i]` -> now a has the value of a + b. this way you won't have to deal with pointers going out of scope etc(documentation of how to return pointers from functions(in a safe way) is [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_pointer_from_functions.htm)).